# Here's a program to find the factorial of a number. Why am I getting 0 as the answer? Which datatype should I use instead?

Tags: c, gcc

I'm relatively new to C. I made this program to find the factorial of any number. Upon executing the program, when I provide 33 as the input - I get 2147483648 as the answer. If I provide 34, I get 0 as the answer.

Getting to my question - Why did I get 0 as the answer? The datatype I've used has a range of 0-4294967295. Am I getting 0 cause this is outside the range of unsigned int? Which datatype should I use if I want to get a large number as the output?

Compiler used - GCC 8.2.1

Here's the code -

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int fact(unsigned int n)
{
        int result;
        if(n==0 || n==1)
                result=1;
        else
                result=n*fact(n-1);
        return result;
}
int main()
{
        unsigned int n,ans;
        printf("Enter n:");
        scanf("%u",&n);
        ans=fact(n);
        printf("Factorial of %u:%u",n,ans);
}
```

Comment: Try `unsigned long long` and with of a bit of luck that goes up to a maximum of `18446744073709551615`. And if that's not enough, you'll have to implement your own arbitrary precision multiplication or use an existing bignum library. If you want to know how high `unsigned long long` goes on your compiler, check `ULLONG_MAX` from `<limits.h>`.

Comment: The factorial grows *very* quickly.  13! is already outside the range representable by a 32-bit unsigned integer.  You get only the 32 least-significant bits for larger inputs.

Comment: Either use a long long or you can use a library which has unbounded ints if that is not enough for your purposes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`33!` is actually way out of the range of a 32 bit `int`, whether signed or unsigned.  `12!` has a value of 479001600, while `13!` has a value of `6227020800`, so you go out of range at `13!`.

Note also that `result` is defined as an `int` and you return an `int` from `fact`.  This means you end up with signed integer overflow which invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).  This can be fixed by changing the type of both to `unsigned`, although you're still limited to `12!`.

You can try using `unsigned long long` for your types instead.  That will get you up to `20!`.  If you want values larger than that, you need to use a bigint library such as GMP.

Answer (score 3):

**The factorial grows very quickly**. 13! is already outside the range representable by a 32-bit unsigned integer. Unsigned arithmetic returns the remainder when a result is not representable -- that is, you get only the least-significant bits of the true mathematical result.  You could go a bit higher by using a wider data type, but not much.  You need an arbitrary-precision arithmetic package and a lot of memory to go much further.

**As for why the result you get for 34! is exactly zero**, note that among the factors 1 * 2 * 3 * ... * 33 * 34 there are 17 that are multiples of two, 8 of which are also multiples of 4, 4 of which are also multiples of 8, two of which are multiples of 16, and one of which is 32.  That's a total of 32 2s in the prime factorization of the mathematical result, so the remainder modulo 2<sup>32</sup> is exactly zero.

Answer (score 1):

An `unsigned int` has a range of `0` to `2^32-1`, or `2^32 = 4,294,967,296` different values. Assigning your `result` a value higher than `2^32-1 = 4,294,967,295` makes the value overflow. This simply means it loops back to `0`, after which it can increase up to `4,294,967,295` again.

The first overflow happens when calculating `13!`, when we would expect the `result` value to be `13! = 6,227,020,800`. However, we did not take the overflow into account. The value of `result` will instead equal the remainder of the equation `13! % 2^32`, or `1,932,053,504`, because that's how much `result` increases after the last (and, in this case, only) loop back to `0`.

Now, `33!` or `34!` represent values that are are unimaginably large, and make `result` overflow many times. We can calculate how many times `33!` causes an overflow simply by dividing it by `2^32`, resulting in around `2.02e27` overflows. However, your question isn't concerned with how many overflows happen, but with the value of the remainder after the last overflow. In this case, it equals [`33! % 2^32 = 2,147,483,648`](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=33!%252%5E32). We can do the same for `34`: [`34! % 2^32 = 0`](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=34!%252%5E32).

What this means is that, coincidentally, `2^32` is a proper divisor of `34!`. Or, isn't this coincidental [after all](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54907489/1418958)?

**Edit**: like others have suggested, you should take a look at [the GMP Bignum library](https://gmplib.org/) with no limit in precision arithmetic except that of your machine.

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption **The datatype I've used has a range of 0-4294967295.** is not right. you define `ans` parameter as `unsigned int` which has range of `0-4294967295` but in your fact function, you are using int which has range of `-2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647`.

So you should change yout code as this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
unsigned int fact(unsigned int n)
{
        unsigned int result;
        if(n==0 || n==1)
                result=1;
        else
                result=n*fact(n-1);
        return result;
}
int main()
{
        unsigned int n,ans;
        printf("Enter n:");
        scanf("%u",&n);
        ans=fact(n);
        printf("Factorial of %u:%u",n,ans);
}
```

You can also use `unsigned long long` instead of `unsigned int` which will support bigger numbers and is more suitable for factorial calculation.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
unsigned long long fact(unsigned int n)
{
        unsigned long long result;
        if(n==0 || n==1)
                result=1;
        else
                result=n*fact(n-1);
        return result;
}
int main()
{
        unsigned int n;
        unsigned long long ans;
        printf("Enter n:");
        scanf("%u",&n);
        ans=fact(n);
        printf("Factorial of %u:%u",n,ans);
}
```

More reading on data types and their range: 
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_data_types.htm

Answer (score 0):

You get 0 when you overflow your data types. Formally the behaviour on overflowing an `int` is *undefined*. If you switch *consistently* to `unsigned` types, then the overflow is such that the behaviour is consistent with arithmetic modulo 2 raised to the power of the number of bits in your `unsigned` type.

Since a large factorial is a multiple of a power of 2, 0 will be attained for a surprisingly small input, as you observe here.

Comment: My happiness is overflowing when I see your posts.

Comment: @SomberoChicken Alas underflow is a form of overflow.